# How to print from a given range of ip addresses every class-c with the last octect replaced by an asterisk

Tags: bash, networking, awk, ip

example:
I have a range from 10.0.100.0 to 10.0.224.0 and I want the output like this:

```
10.0.100.*
10.0.101.*
10.0.102.*
```

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 10.0.{100..224}.\*
10.0.100.*
10.0.101.*
10.0.102.*
10.0.103.*
10.0.104.*
10.0.105.*
[...snip...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed`:

```
$ sed -i 's/[0-9]\+$/\*/' file.txt 
10.0.100.*
10.0.101.*
10.0.102.*
```

**EDIT:** *If you want to generate the range first and then replace the last octet try this:*

To generate the range you can use `echo 10.0.{100..224}.0 | tr ' ' '\n'` (John1024's answer shows another way using `printf`).

Now to replace the last octet with `*` and save it to a file:

```
$ echo 10.0.{100..224}.0 | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/[0-9]\+$/\*/' > output.txt
```

If you just want to print the output:

```
$echo 10.0.{100..224}.0 | tr ' ' '\n' | sed -n 's/[0-9]\+$/\*/p'
```

Although in your case i would suggest you to just make the last octet `*` while generating the range (check [John1024's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192053/68757)).